# Need to highlight the column when header is dragged from one position to other position in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

In sortable jquery start event is present when we start dragging event is fired but in jqgrid its not working

Here update is working but when i replace update with start/stop/change events it is not working how to get drag event for reordering the columns.

```
sortable: {
            update: function(event, ui) 
            {
               window.setTimeout(setColor, 500);
             }
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Start event started working when it is inside the options tag

```
 sortable: {  options : { 
                 cursor:'move', 
                start: function(event, ui) 
                 {
                    alert('hi');
                 }
               }},
}
```